# How to export dataset to excel using CodeXml in C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I got this `Error` :

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233036
>   Message=The type initializer for 'ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook' threw an
>   exception.   Source=ClosedXML   TypeName=ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook
>   StackTrace:
>          at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor()
>          at ClosedXml.Form1.ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds) in c:\users\test\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ClosedXml\ClosedXml\Form1.cs:line 41
>          at ClosedXml.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\test\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ClosedXml\ClosedXml\Form1.cs:line 30
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   InnerException:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>          HResult=-2147024894
>          Message=Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>          Source=ClosedXML
>          FileName=DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>          FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///c:/users/test/documents/visual studio
>   2010/Projects/ClosedXml/ClosedXml/bin/Debug/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath
>   = NULL Calling assembly : ClosedXML, Version=0.69.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fd1eb21b62ae805b.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: No application configuration file found. LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
>   Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///c:/users/test/documents/visual studio
>   2010/Projects/ClosedXml/ClosedXml/bin/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///c:/users/test/documents/visual studio
>   2010/Projects/ClosedXml/ClosedXml/bin/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///c:/users/test/documents/visual studio
>   2010/Projects/ClosedXml/ClosedXml/bin/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///c:/users/test/documents/visual studio
>   2010/Projects/ClosedXml/ClosedXml/bin/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EXE.
>
> ```
>    StackTrace:
>         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..cctor()
>    InnerException:
> ```

And I am using the Code below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Country");
    dt.Rows.Add("Venkatesh", "India");
    dt.Rows.Add("Santhosh", "USA");
    dt.Rows.Add("Venkat Sai", "Dubai");
    dt.Rows.Add("Venkat Teja", "Pakistan");
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    ExportDataSetToExcel(ds);
}
public  void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds)
{
    string AppLocation = "";
    AppLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    AppLocation = AppLocation.Replace("file:\\", "");
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    date = date.Replace("/", "_");
    string filepath = AppLocation + "\\ExcelFiles\\" + "RECEIPTS_COMPARISON_" + date + ".xlsx";

    using (ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wb = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
             wb.Worksheets.Add(ds.Tables[i], ds.Tables[i].TableName);
        }
        wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = ClosedXML.Excel.XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        wb.SaveAs(filepath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested with 0.94.2, no problem occur

Comment: provide me codeXml.dll file please

Comment: `PM> Install-Package ClosedXML` here bro https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: @TấnNguyên Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use another way to convert dataset to excel by using office API.

Code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
        table1.TableName = "Student";
        table1.Columns.Add("Name");
        table1.Columns.Add("Id");
        table1.Columns.Add("Age");
        table1.Rows.Add("test1", 1001, 22);
        table1.Rows.Add("test2", 1005, 24);
        table1.Rows.Add("test3", 1007, 26);
        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        table2.TableName = "Product";
        table2.Columns.Add("ProductName");
        table2.Columns.Add("Date");
        table2.Columns.Add("Address");
        table2.Rows.Add("test1", "2020-01-01", "home");
        table2.Rows.Add("test2", "2020-02-01", "Company");
        table2.Rows.Add("test3", "2020-03-01", "School");
        set.Tables.Add(table1);
        set.Tables.Add(table2);
        ExportDataSetToExcel(set, "D:\\test.xlsx");
        MessageBox.Show("success");
    }
    private void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds, string path)
    {
        //Creae an Excel application instance
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        //Create an Excel workbook instance and open it from the predefined location
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        int count = 1;
        foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            //Add a new worksheet to workbook with the Datatable name
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
            excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;

            for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                }
            }
            if(count<ds.Tables.Count)
            {
                excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add(excelWorkSheet);
            }

            count++;
        }

        excelWorkBook.SaveAs(path);
        excelWorkBook.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: error `Excel cannot open the file 'test.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.`

Comment: Sorry for the error, I have updated my code. Based on my test, the above code can convert the dataset to excel successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the version of the `ClosedXML` NuGet Package from `Version=0.69.1.0` to `Version=0.94.2`.

Comment: latest version ClosedXml how to download

Comment: Use console manager in Visual studio or go to NuGet package manager.